# Why do cores in the computation scheduler work on distinct cores in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

The main question is in the title, so I'll clarify a bit. I understand that count of threads in the computation scheduler equals to the amount of CPU cores. But why do these threads MUST run on separate cores? Is there any difference in creation of these threads or something? Because we can spawn 100 threads or even more and they will block each other but 4 computation threads will run parallel anyway though in my mind it looks like these 4 threads may be dispatched to the same thread too.

Possibly, I described it dirty I cannot make my thoughts straight but I hope you understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

It improves cache locality for computation, which would otherwise likely bounce all around between cores with traditional thread pools. However, it is subject to the underlying OS scheduler behavior so worker-cpu core assignment is not guaranteed by RxJava. The idea is that fully saturated workers will be assigned to distinct cores.

All standard scheduler workers are single threaded threadpools underneath for this purpose and also to guarantee total ordering of runnables and avoid reentrance. This allows operators to be less complicated with practically no extra cost on the scheduler side.

`Schedulers.from` does and can't make this type of thread locality so if you are fine with bouncing around, you can simply wrap an `Executor` with it.

Comment: It there a resource where I could read about it more? Maybe a book? I don't know why, but it seems a lot of people found it obvious to understand, except me =)